# "firstly ... secondly ..." or "first ... second ... "?

Tags: difference, adverbs, lists

Suppose I am enumerating reasons not to fly. Is it then correct to write/say:

> Firstly, I prefer the train because I can see the landscape. Secondly, I have control over my luggage, and thirdly, it is better for the environment.

Or is it:

> First, I prefer the train because I can see the landscape. Second, I have control over my luggage, and third, it is better for the environment.

I thought the first should be correct, but I find the second one in written texts. Which one is correct?

Comment: Firstly, secondly, thirdly, all right. But please, not fourthly or fifthly or seventeenthly. It's not incorrect, it's just ugly.

Comment: I prefer "First of all," which I feel helps resolve the seeming discrepancy of non-parallel language in continuing to "secondly."

Answer (score 61, accepted):

Both styles are used. In most genres, no-one will object to either. However, traditionally, ***first, secondly, thirdly*** etc. is used. Only pedants will insist on this usage, but it is something to be aware of, as there are many pedants. See *Fowler's Modern English Usage* (3rd edition).

The Oxford English Dictionary on *firstly*:

> Used only in enumerating heads, topics, etc. in discourse; and many writers prefer *first*, even though closely followed by *secondly, thirdly*, etc.

Burchfield in *Fowler's Modern English Usage* on *first*:

[image]

Comment: My native-speaking ears prefer *first*, *second*, *third*.

Answer (score 18):

*First*, and *firstly* are both correct, since *first* is also an adverb. So you can say:

> I prefer the train because I can see the landscape. Secondly, I have control over my luggage, and thirdly, it is better for the environment.

> First, I prefer the train because I can see the landscape. Second, I have control over my luggage, and third, it is better for the environment.

The important thing is not to mix them, as in the following sentence:

> First, I prefer the train because I can see the landscape. Secondly, I have control over my luggage.

Comment: I'm sorry, but your last statement is not right. The traditional sequence is *first, secondly, thirdly* etc.

Comment: @Cerberus Then the NOAD is wrong too.

Comment: NOAD is wrong, really? I have never used it. In any case, leaf through a few books and you will find *first, secondly* all over the place. It is perfectly correct and even the preferred choice for many.

Comment: Are you sure NOAD didn't say "*don't use firstly, second, thirdly*, nor *first, secondly, third*"? The order of the -ly's is important.

Comment: "Make sure not to mix the two groups: _first_, _second_, _third_; not _first_, _secondly_, _thirdly_."

Comment: Okay, that is simply wrong. Consult any style guide, like Fowler's.

Comment: Is it wrong basing on what? What said from a style guide is not more correct than what reported from a dictionary. The purpose of style guides is not saying what it is correct, but providing a guide.

Comment: You and NOAD are saying *first, secondly* is wrong. That is a very broad claim. If significant evidence can be found that respectable authors use *first, secondly*, your claim is invalidated. I have added a quotation from the Oxford English Dictionary in my answer.

Comment: I didn't say "it is wrong"; I said "the important is not mixing them." Style guides are not _evidences_, nor does _traditional order_ have any relevance.

Comment: I think that Burchfield, in *Fowler's*, has hit it: "Logic did not and does not come into it."  Gowers, in the second edition of *Fowler's* (1965), says "The preference for *first* over *firstly* in formal enumerations is one of those harmless pedantries in which those who like oddities because they are odd are free to indulge, provided that they abstain from censuring those who do not share their liking."

Answer (score 3):

[This answer at ELU](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/1834/26446) suggests:

> Both are correct, however, there is "overcorrectness" in using *firstly* because it seems more like an adverb than *first*.
>
> Go on the length principle: both have the same meaning, but *firstly* is two characters longer than *first*. The language will eventually evolve to do without the longer equivalent; I'd use *first*.

Comment: That should be *principle*, not *principal*

Comment: @jwpat7 It's a quoted text from another article. Since you have modified it there, I will update it here. Is it fine?

Comment: Yes, thanks.  (Aside: It appears that for some inscrutable reason somebody downvoted your answer; I myself upvoted your answer because it provides a link to other useful ELU answers, although I don't find this particular quoted rationale compelling.)

Comment: @jwpat7 If the answer is bad, I don't mind it being downvoted. There's a [discussion on Meta](http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/questions/170/are-answers-that-merely-quote-an-existing-answer-on-elu-acceptable), please join. If the community decides to discourage such answers, so be it.

Answer (score 1):

From [Cambridge website](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/first-firstly-or-at-first), mentioned:

> We often use first, especially in writing, to show the order of the
>   points we want to make. When we are making lists, we can use first or
>   firstly. Firstly is more formal than first

So, If you are doing academic writing use Firstly, otherwise, use First for general writing use.

Answer (score 0):

From this [ELU post first answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1824/firstly-or-first/), it is said that:

> Eric Partridge ("Usage and Abusage") says:
>
> **firstly** is traditionally said to be inferior to *first*, even when *secondly*, *thirdly* ... follow it.

As many others have mentioned, both are perfectly fine. Additionally "firstly" is more formal than "first" to most. Another [ELL answer](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/70771/is-it-correct-in-formal-writing-to-use-firstly-alone/70776#70776) on that can be found on it (add on @Dongrui_Yang's answer).

Some alternatives are found [here](https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/informal-style-firstly-moreover.2530129/):

> firstly = first off / "for a start..."
>
> secondly = next / and then / another thing
>
> moreover/furthermore = on top of that/this

It is said by [Grammarist](https://grammarist.com/usage/firstly-secondly-thirdly/) that:

> “Firstly,” “secondly,” and “thirdly” are [superfluous terms](https://grammarist.com/superfluous-words/). “First,” “second,” and “third” are more acceptable words for enumerating text in writing. Experts also prefer “first” even if the other items state “secondly” and “thirdly.”

It is also said from [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/words-at-play/first-or-firstly) that:

> In writing, **first** is much more common than *firstly* and is probably the best bet for most situations, even if the only reason is that a reader may wonder if *firstly* is proper and be distracted by this word choice.

Answer (score -2):

If you are writing as a list (which most intend), use first, second and third. After all, if reading as a list of prioritised numbers, say, you wouldn't retort 'onely'; it would be 'one', 'two' and so on. Hence first, second etc.  No need for the ly. This 'error' of 'firstly' etc is almost annoying as the improper use of 'which' (without punctuation), when most should actually be using 'that'.....